# How to use Parallel Web Workers?

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, web-worker

I need to Process **100** image files in parallel. I have divided it into 3 streams.

```
async process(){
for (const key in this.files) {
  let i: number = Number(key);
  if( i % 3 === 0)
  this.files[i].thumb = (await this.fn(key, this.files[key])).data.thumb;
}
for (const key in this.files) {
  let i: number = Number(key);
  if( i % 3 === 1)
  this.files[i].thumb = (await this.fn(key, this.files[key])).data.thumb;
}
for (const key in this.files) {
  let i: number = Number(key);
  if( i % 3 === 2)
  this.files[i].thumb = (await this.fn(key, this.files[key])).data.thumb;
}
}
```

I very well know this is not parallel. How do I make this function parallel? (Also I need to pass the number of parallel tasks as an argument.

How can I achieve this?

---

I tried a few variations but no luck. This just makes a pool of 3. :(

```
async process(){
let queue: Promise<any>[] = [];
for (let index = 0; index < this.files.length; index+=3) {
  let i = index;

  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    if(this.files[i+j]) queue.push(this.createThumbnail(i+j, this.files[i+j]))

  let respArr = await Promise.all(queue);
  console.log(respArr);

  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    if(respArr[j]) this.files[i+j].thumb = respArr[j].data.thumb;

  queue = [];
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to start by `n` number of jobs and once each one of these jobs finished, start a new one until there is no job left.
Have a look at this code:

```js
const queue = []
let pointer = 0
let resolvedCount = 0

const start = (fn, files, n) => {
  while (pointer < n) queue.push(createPromise(files[pointer], fn))
}

const createPromise = (file, fn) => {
  let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fn(files[pointer], function(data) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(data.thumb)
      }, pointer * 1000);
    })
    pointer += 1
  })
  promise.then(function(thumb) {
    resolvedCount += 1
    console.log(thumb, "resolved!")
    if (files[pointer]) {
      queue.push(createPromise(files[pointer], fn))
    }
    if (resolvedCount === files.length) {
      Promise.all(queue).then(done)
    }
  })
  return promise
}

const done = (values) => {
  console.log(values)
}

const files = [{
    thumb: 'a'
  },
  {
    thumb: 'b'
  },
  {
    thumb: 'c'
  },
  {
    thumb: 'd'
  },
  {
    thumb: 'e'
  }
]
const fn = (x, f) => f(x)

start(
    fn, //the function you want to apply on each entry
    files, //the array you want to do a job on
    2 // number of parallel jobs
)
```